# Laravel fetchi API Data + vue

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, jsonplaceholder

Getting to know Laravel a bit more and I was wondering what's the best way to pass my data from my controller into my Vue component?

I have understood how to actually pass it as a prop, however, I can't seem to get it to render the way I want. my props in my Vue component are. My controller here:

```
{
    public function fetch() {

        $data = Http::get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums')->json();
        return view('welcome', ['data' => $data]);
    }
}

My view then passes on the data to my vue component like this. 
<example-component :albums="@json($data)" />

My Vue props structure is below.

props: {
    albums: {
      type: Array,
      default: []
    },
  }
```

Heres how im trying to render the data in my vue component:

```
    <div>
        <h1 v-for="album in albums" :key="album.id">
            {{ album.title }}
        </h1>
    </div>
</template>
```

Results here [enter link description here](https://gyazo.com/28b8dc82508a948057c96925e83f9c49)

I have verified the output from my controller is an array containing arrays. Am I handling the data wrong from the perspective of my Vue component?

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to convert it to json `:albums="@json($data)"` it's already json `->json();`

try replace

```
:albums="@json($data)"
```

with this

```
:albums="{{ $data }}"
```

Comment: Thankyou, however, i got this error when doing that.

https://i.gyazo.com/400a208c777f40a5ae74e84db65bd586.png

Comment: @Freddy then the issue is not from PHP or laravel, check the Vue component

Comment: Here is how my props are built, is it incorrect?

props: {
    albums: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },
        },